# Can not get the expected result in many to many relationship using LINQ in Asp.net C#, MVC, Codefirst application

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq, ef-code-first

I'm trying to develop an application using Asp.net C#, MVC, Codefirst approach.

I have two classes as Actors and Movies, which has many to many relationships. (An actor can have many movies, a movie can have many actors)

Now i'm facing a problem, I can retrieve data from both tables but not as expected, I believe something is going wrong at somewhere with the logic of my code.

For instance, I can retrieve a list of movies from database and when i click on each movie it redirects me to the page that belongs to that particular movie which makes sense up to this point, but now i want to retrieve the list of actors that has played role in this particular movie and here i fail. (I can retrieve the whole list of actors that exist in database but not the particular actors that has played role in a particular movie).

These are my models:

This is the Actor Class:

```
public class Actors
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Actor_Name { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Movies> mvzz { get; set; }


}
```

And this is the movies class:

```
public class Movies
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Movie_title { get; set; }
    public string genre { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Actors> actzz { get; set; }

}
```

This is the controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var mvz = _context.mvz;
        return View(mvz);
    }

      public ActionResult Details(int? Id)
     {

        var movies_Detail = _context.mvz.Include(a=> a.actzz).SingleOrDefault(i=> i.Id==Id);
        var actors = _context.act.ToList();

        var ViewModel = new MoviesActorsViewModel()
        {
            Movies = movies_Detail,
            Actors = actors

        };
        return View(ViewModel);
    }
    }
}
```

This is the Index View which shows the list of Movies and has a link for the details of each movie individually:

```
@model IEnumerable<mtmmmmmm.Models.Movies> 

 @{
  ViewBag.Title = "Index";
  Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
 }
 <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-responsive">


@foreach (var mvz in Model)
{
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>@mvz.Id</td>
            <td>@Html.ActionLink(mvz.Movie_title, "Details","Movies", new { Id = mvz.Id },null)</td>

        </tr>
    </tbody>
}
```

This is the the details view that has to shows the detailed information of of each movie, very particularly It has to show the list of Actors that has played role in that particular movie.

```
   @model  mtmmmmmm.ViewModel.MoviesActorsViewModel
   @{
   ViewBag.Title = "Details";
   Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
   }

    <h2>The list of Actors that has played role in @Model.Movies.Movie_title</h2>

    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-responsive"> 

    @foreach (var actors in Model.Actors)
    {
        <tbody>
            <tr>

                    <td>@actors.Id</td>
                    <td>@actors.Actor_Name</td>
                    <td>@actors.Country</td>


            </tr>
        </tbody>

    }
```

And Finally this is the View Model:

```
  public class MoviesActorsViewModel
  {
    public List<Actors> Actors { get; set; }
    public Movies Movies { get; set; }



    public MoviesActorsViewModel()
    {
        Actors = new List<Actors>();
        Movies = new Movies();

    }


}
```

I know that something is wrong with the LINQ logic that i'm writing to retrieve the list of actors in the controller class.

If anyone having expertise in this regard is reading this post, Kindly guide me with the correct logic that i should use for LINQ or any other apporach that helps me get the result.

Many thanks in advance for taking your time and reading this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to change

```
var actors = _context.act.ToList();
```

to

```
var actors = movies_Detail.actzz.ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked & you were very helpful.